# Lense compatibility

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I'm planning to move from P&S to DSLR and have shortlisted **Canon 550D** & **Nikon D5100**

But my friend suggested me to go for the Canon as the Nikon DSLR will not support most of the new lenses ! So I'm bit confused :|
I'll use the camera for outdoor photography, landscape, family picture mainly, and rarely for video , low light photography.
Which one does suite my needs ?

Comment: That's not true at all, D5100 is compatible with ALL new Nikon lenses, that's AF-S and AF-I lenses, just because it doesn't have an AF motor, you will not have auto-focus if you use OLD AF lenses, but you could still use focus manually with older lenses.

Comment: I would stop listening to that person for photography related advice. They have no idea what they are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Both Canon and Nikon offer full lines of DSLR lenses, both APS-C sensor sized lenses and full frame(35mm) lenses.

We have many questions already that address your concerns and further details of it:

- [What are the most notable differences between Canon and Nikon lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3363/what-are-the-most-notable-differences-between-canon-and-nikon-lenses)
- [What's the difference between the Canon and Nikon lenses mounts?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8527/whats-the-difference-between-the-canon-and-nikon-lenses-mounts)
- [Are Nikon lens double the cost of Canon auto-focus lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25084/are-nikon-lens-double-the-cost-of-canon-auto-focus-lens/25088#25088)

Generally speaking there is no reason a beginner, based on lens needs, should chose either brand over the other. This question should help you out with the basic differences:

[Is there any significant difference between Nikon and Canon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12746/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-nikon-and-canon)

Comment: Thnx for your valuable info :)  ,but which one you will advice for me ?

Comment: @Sourav - This is what you should be reading to chose your first DSLR - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/what-should-i-look-for-when-shopping-for-my-first-dslr/2877#2877